# Chrome storage not being set

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Code:

```
function save(){
    chrome.storage.sync.set({"test": "123"}, function(){
        console.log("Value is set");
    });
}
```

This function is located in my background script but when called doesn't save anything.

The storage permission is granted in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Have you correctly given storage permission to your extension in the extension manifest ? [https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKwQK.png)

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention that it already had the permission.